# Power Query - regional settings

Tags: delimiter, powerquery, regional-settings

I've made a best practice sheet for my department, which works perfectly on my own computer (en-US regional settings), but when I sent it to a coworker, everything blew up (da-DK regional settings).

Half the department uses en-US and the other half uses da-DK. It's not an option for everybody to use the same, so I'd like to create a sheet that can handle both automatically.

The csv files created in en-US uses "," delimiter and a "." for decimal, while the da-DK settings uses ";" as delimiter and "," for decimals.

How would I best go about this issue?

I have the following two identical data queries

Data1.csv:

```
    Panel/Node/Case,    MXX (kNm/m),    MYY (kNm/m)
    1/ 1/ 1,            145.46,         145.46  
    1/ 1/ 2,            98.83,          98.83   
    1/ 1/ 3 (C),        244.30,         244.30  
    1/ 2/ 1,            19.80,          19.80   
    1/ 2/ 2,            13.46,          13.46   
    1/ 2/ 3 (C),        33.26,          33.26   
    1/ 3/ 1,            19.80,          19.80   
    1/ 3/ 2,            13.46,          13.46   
    1/ 3/ 3 (C),        33.26,          33.26   
    1/ 4/ 1,            145.46,         145.46  
    1/ 4/ 2,            98.83,          98.83   
    1/ 4/ 3 (C),        244.30,         244.30
```

Data2.csv:

```
    Panel/Node/Case;    MXX (kNm/m);    MYY (kNm/m)
    1/ 1/ 1;            145,46;         145,46
    1/ 1/ 2;            98,83;          98,83
    1/ 1/ 3 (C);        244,30;         244,30
    1/ 2/ 1;            19,80;          19,80
    1/ 2/ 2;            13,46;          13,46
    1/ 2/ 3 (C);        33,26;          33,26
    1/ 3/ 1;            19,80;          19,80
    1/ 3/ 2;            13,46;          13,46
    1/ 3/ 3 (C);        33,26;          33,26
    1/ 4/ 1;            145,46;         145,46
    1/ 4/ 2;            98,83;          98,83
    1/ 4/ 3 (C);        244,30;         244,30
```

I was considering to use a replace values function to replace the characters I need, but as both queries contain a "," that proves difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is some dynamic/built-in means of detecting a file's content's locale and delimiter. I haven't found one yet. Until someone comes along and points out a better way of doing this, maybe the below can serve as an interim solution.

- The `parseCsv` function in the code below attempts to infer the delimiter (it assumes that the delimiter will always be present in the first line of the CSV, immediately after `Panel/Node/Case`).
- It also tries to transform the last two columns' values from text to numbers (by replacing `,` with `.`). If you don't want this behaviour, you can delete it from the code. Also, this transformation will only work for locales that use `.` for the decimal separator. (If you need to support other cultures/locales, it might make more sense to try to infer the culture/locale and pass it as a second argument to `Number.FromText`.)

---

```
let
    data1 = Text.ToBinary(
    "Panel/Node/Case,    MXX (kNm/m),    MYY (kNm/m)
    1/ 1/ 1,            145.46,         145.46  
    1/ 1/ 2,            98.83,          98.83   
    1/ 1/ 3 (C),        244.30,         244.30  
    1/ 2/ 1,            19.80,          19.80   
    1/ 2/ 2,            13.46,          13.46   
    1/ 2/ 3 (C),        33.26,          33.26   
    1/ 3/ 1,            19.80,          19.80   
    1/ 3/ 2,            13.46,          13.46   
    1/ 3/ 3 (C),        33.26,          33.26   
    1/ 4/ 1,            145.46,         145.46  
    1/ 4/ 2,            98.83,          98.83   
    1/ 4/ 3 (C),        244.30,         244.30", TextEncoding.Utf8),

    data2 = Text.ToBinary(
    "Panel/Node/Case;    MXX (kNm/m);    MYY (kNm/m)
    1/ 1/ 1;            145,46;         145,46
    1/ 1/ 2;            98,83;          98,83
    1/ 1/ 3 (C);        244,30;         244,30
    1/ 2/ 1;            19,80;          19,80
    1/ 2/ 2;            13,46;          13,46
    1/ 2/ 3 (C);        33,26;          33,26
    1/ 3/ 1;            19,80;          19,80
    1/ 3/ 2;            13,46;          13,46
    1/ 3/ 3 (C);        33,26;          33,26
    1/ 4/ 1;            145,46;         145,46
    1/ 4/ 2;            98,83;          98,83
    1/ 4/ 3 (C);        244,30;         244,30", TextEncoding.Utf8),

    parseCsv = (someFile as binary) =>
        let
            lines = Lines.FromBinary(someFile, QuoteStyle.Csv, false, TextEncoding.Utf8),
            firstLine = List.First(lines),
            expectedDelimiterPosition = Text.Length("Panel/Node/Case"), 
            delimiterInferred = Text.At(firstLine, expectedDelimiterPosition),
            csv = Csv.Document(someFile, [Delimiter = delimiterInferred, Encoding = TextEncoding.Utf8, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.Csv]),
            promoted = Table.PromoteHeaders(csv, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
            lastTwoColumnsAsNumbers = 
                let
                    lastTwoHeaders = List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(promoted), 2),
                    replaceAndConvertToNumber = (someText as text) as number => Number.From(Text.Replace(someText, ",", ".")),
                    transformers = List.Transform(lastTwoHeaders, each {_, replaceAndConvertToNumber, type number}),
                    transformed = Table.TransformColumns(promoted, transformers)
                in transformed
        in lastTwoColumnsAsNumbers,
    parsed1 = parseCsv(data1),
    parsed2 = parseCsv(data2),
    parsed3 = parseCsv(File.Contents("C:\Users\MRCH\Desktop\Data1.csv"))
in
    parsed3
```

---

- To implement this, you can copy the code above, create a blank query (in my version of Excel, I do this via: Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Blank Query), click Advanced Editor (near the top left), delete any existing code, paste what you've copied, then click "Done".
- To make the `parseCsv` function work with a file path, you could for example change `parsed1 = parseCsv(data1)` to `parsed1 = parseCsv(File.Contents("SOME_FILE_PATH"))` where `SOME_FILE_PATH` is the file path to `Data1.csv` on your machine (keep the double quotes).
- In the Query Editor, you can click on and view expressions/steps `parsed1` and `parsed2` (which are basically what the `parseCsv` function returns for `Data1.csv` and `Data2.csv` respectively). `data1` and `data2` are just there for demonstrative purposes and you'd replace them with the actual binary content of your CSVs.

If that doesn't help, let me know where I can improve my explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! This is a bit over my ability though, so I'm not sure how exactly to proceed from there, so a working example would be of great help!

Comment: @Martin, I have re-written parts of my answer, if you want to have another look.

Comment: Thanks, but the main thing that I don't understand is how to import the data? Usually I'd use "Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\MRCH\Desktop\Data1.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1200, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])" But how does that translate into what you've written? I'd like to import the CSV file, while you have "defined" it inside the query?

Comment: Try `parseCsv(File.Contents("C:\Users\MRCH\Desktop\Data1.csv"))` assuming you have the function `parseCsv` included in your code. Have added a `parsed3` expression/step as an example, so you can see if it works for your files or not.

Comment: Fantastic everything seems to be working. Thank you very much for your help!